# JOSE4J: How to create a RsaJsonWebKey object from a JSON representation of RsaJsonWebKey

Tags: json, unmarshalling, jose4j

I want to save with JOSE4J the JSON representation of a RsaJsonWebKey object in JSON format and then recreate a RsaJsonWebKey  object from it again. I have the marshalling part:

RsaJsonWebKey rsaJsonWebKey = RsaJwkGenerator.generateJwk(2048);

String jwkjson = rsaJsonWebKey.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.INCLUDE_PRIVATE);

but how to unmarshall it and recreate RsaJsonWebKey. That is where I'm stuck as I don't see a constructor of RsaJsonWebKey allowing that.

The question is related to this question

[JWT becomes invalid after restarting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913901/jwt-becomes-invalid-after-restarting-the-server)

but it doesn't explain how to unmarshall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bottom half of the example in [JWT becomes invalid after restarting the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913901) does show how to get to a JsonWebKey/PublicJsonWebKey object from a JSON string.  Using `PublicJsonWebKey publicJsonWebKey = PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(jwkJson);` will do the parsing/unmarshalling and can be cast to `RsaJsonWebKey` if need be.

Comment: Hi Brian, I wanted to use a none encrypted JSON string. I looked in the sources of JOSE4J and it's possible like this i got the feeling. Haven't tried it yet: Map<String,Object> jwkJsonParsed = JsonUtil.parseJson(jwkJson);
     RsaJsonWebKey RsaJsonWebKeyRecreated = new RsaJsonWebKey(jwkJsonParsed); ... where jwkJson is the json string i got via String jwkJson = rsaJsonWebKey.toJson(JsonWebKey.OutputControlLevel.INCLUDE_PRIVATE);

Comment: PublicJsonWebKey.Factory.newPublicJwk(jwkJson) will parse the JWK JSON into a PublicJsonWebKey object, which will be an instance of RsaJsonWebKey if it's an RSA key. You shouldn't have to do any of that that you mention. But it should work too.

Comment: I just used `JsonWebKey.Factory.newJwk(json) as RsaJsonWebKey` to load key for creating new jwt tokens